# How to determine equivalence between `ranges::view` object and `std::vector`?

Tags: compare, comparison, stdvector, range-v3

I'm using the excellent [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library. One of my functions returns a `ranges::view` object which I'd like to compare to a `std::vector`. Of course, I can compare element-by-element, but there's got to be a better way.

> How to determine equivalence between `ranges::view` object and `std::vector`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if two ranges refer to sequences of equal elements, pass them to the `ranges::equal` algorithm ([**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/drelV5N7D53atok6)):

```
int main() {
  std::vector<int> vec{5,4,3,2,1,0};
  assert(ranges::equal(vec, ranges::view::iota(0, 6) | ranges::view::reverse));
}
```

Comment: I like the ranges library, but often with thorough and complete libraries, it is difficult to know where to find the answer. Thanks for the help!